# How can I get System.Data with dnu?

Tags: dnx, dnu

Trying to find out what version I need to get my project.json to pull the libraries I need.

Right now I'm trying to get `System.Data` so that I can use a DataSet.

Trying to brute force my way with a Curl:

```
curl https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.data/index.json
```

And I see it is not found...

I was able to get

```
curl https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.data.sqlcient/index.json
```

Where is the documentation for what is available?

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Dependency-Resolution

I'm getting pretty close, but still no cigar.

At least I was able to compile!

```
mcs TestExample.cs -r:System.Data.dll
```

but not with Dnx.

Answer (score 1):

I think `System.Data` is a desktop CLR only, GAC-ed assembly. So you'll have to add it the `frameworkAssemblies` section in `project.json` similar to this example: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/7ac7929aa575e17b3c271e4a7a0c164418de0395/misc/ProjectToProject/src/P1/project.json#L9-L12

You will probably not be able to target CoreCLR, unless you find a replacement for this library.

Comment: Thanks Victor! For a future unknowing reader GAC is Global Assembly Cache. BTW, how can I figure out what are my options for framework assemblies or dependencies?